# Set different body background for different pages when using AngularJS template and ui-router

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have two pages and I'm using `ui.router` to jump around different pages. One is a login page and after login, the page will jump to a home page.I want to set the a body `background-color` for login page but set another body `background-color` for another. If I just set color for the template `div`, the color won't be applied to the body background, but if set color directly to the background, then two pages have the same color. What can I do?

**HTML:**

```
 <body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app',[....]).config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/',
            views:{
                'content':{
                    templateUrl:"views/login.html",
                    controller:"LoginController"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home',{
            url:'/home',
            views:{
                'header':{
                    templateUrl : "views/header.html",
                    controller: 'HeaderController'                                             
                },
                'content':{
                    templateUrl: "views/homePage.html",
                    controller : 'HomeController'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Add `background-color` to root tag (may be `ion-view` tag) of your `homePage` template using `bg-color` inline attribute. or from CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a global controller (which is applied to either `<html>` or `<body>` tag), register an event:

```
myApp.controller('GlobalCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Event listener for state change.
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        $scope.bodyClass = toState.name + '-page';
    });
});
```

Now, in your HTML:

```
<body class="{{bodyClass}} foo bar" ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
   <!-- your content -->
</body>
```

Now, in your CSS:

```
body.login-page {
    background: green;
}

body.home-page {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For index page:

```
<body ng-class="{'home-page': $state.includes('home'), 'login-page' : $state.includes('login')}">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
</body>
```

For app.run.js, add this code first.

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

CSS:

```
body.home-page {
  background: yellow;
}

body.login-page {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using angular-router, from your main app you will get an event **$statechangeSuccess**, when the state gets changed you will get to know on which state you are and probably change the background using **ng-style** or **ng-class** on body:

HTML

```
<body ng-class='{$scope.state==="home":class1,$scope.state==="login":class2}'>
```

JS

```
    app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
$scope.state = toState;//do the checking
      });
    });
```